# (Pre)Sheaves of abelian groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, presheaves

Let $X$ be a topological space, $A$ an abelian group, $p\in X$. Define the presheaf $i_p(A)$ to be $$i_p(A)(U):=\begin{cases} \text{A}, & \text{if } p\in U \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$ with restriction map $$\rho_{UV}=\begin{cases} \text{id}_A, & \text{if } p\in V \\0, &\text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$ $\forall U\subset V$ open, $V\subseteq U$ open in $X$.

I showed this is actually a sheaf of abelian groups looking at the constant sheaf, which is the sheafification of $i_p$.

Now, I have to show that:

1. the stalk $i_p(A)$ at a point $q\in X$ is $A$ if $q \in \overline{\{p\}}$ closure of $\{p\}$ in $X$, and $(0)$ in all other cases;
2. Let $A_Y$ be the constant sheaf on $Y:=\overline{\{p\}}$ associated with the abelian group $A$. Let $i:Y\rightarrow X$ denote the natural inclusion. Show that there exists a canonical isomorphism of sheaves between $i_*A_Y$ and $i_p(A)$.

I am just started studying (pre)sheaves in algebraic geometry and I am not getting some points yet. I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: What are you not getting? For (1), you need to compute the stalk so you need to compute the direct limit. For (2), you need to exhibit an isomorphism of sheaves, so going by definition is where I would start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{(1) proof:}$

- If $q\in\overline{\{p\}}$ then $\exists V\subset X$ open such that $q\in V$.
  Note that we also have $p\in V$ otherwise $p\in X\setminus V$ which is closed, contradiction. The map $$(i_p(A))_q\rightarrow A$$ $$[(U,s)]\mapsto s$$
  is well-defined: if  $(U,s)\sim(V,t)$ then $\exists W$ open with $p,q\in W$ such that $$\rho_{U,W}(s)=\text{id}_A(s)=\text{id}_A(t)=\rho_{V,W}(t)\Rightarrow s=t.$$
  It is injective: $(U,s)\sim(V,t)\Rightarrow U\cap V$ is open. Hence $p,q\in U\cap V$ and $\rho_{U,U\cap V}(s)=\rho_{V,U\cap V}(s)\Rightarrow (U,s)\sim (V,t)$. It is surjective: $(X,s)$ is a preimage of $s\in A$.
- If $q\notin\overline{\{p\}}$, take $(U,s),(V,t)\in (i_p(A))_q$. Define $W:U\cap V\cap X\setminus \overline{\{p\}}$, it is open and non nempty because $q\in U,V,X$. Now, since $i_p(A)(U)$ is trivial we have $$\rho_{U,W}(s)=0=\rho_{V,W}(t)\Rightarrow (U,s)\sim(V,t)$$ so $(i_p(A)(-))_q=0$.

$\textbf{(2) proof:}$
$A_Y(U)=\{f:U\rightarrow A, \text{continuous with discrete topology on }A\}$, $i_*A_Y(U)=A_Y(i^{-1}(U))=A_Y(U\cap Y)$. For any $U\subseteq X$ open, define $$i_*A_Y(U)\rightarrow i_p(A)(U)$$ $$F\mapsto \begin{cases} F(p), & \text{if }p\in U \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$
It is well-defined: easily check that it is compatible with restrictions $\Rightarrow$ morphism of presheaf $\Rightarrow$ morphism of sheaves. Take $q\in Y$ $$(i_*(A_y))_q\rightarrow(i_p(A))_q\xrightarrow{(1)}A$$ $$[(U,f)]\mapsto(U,f(p))\mapsto f(p).$$
It is injective: $(V,f),(U,g)$ such that $f(p)=g(p)$, then it agrees on the connected components of $p\in V\cap U\Rightarrow (V,f)\sim (U,g)$.
It is surjective: $(X,f(x\mapsto a))$ for $a\in A$ is a preimage of $A$. Hence there is a canonical isomorphism $(i_*A_Y)_q\rightarrow(i_p(A))_q$.